# Laravel Composer install error on bootstrap logger

Tags: laravel

> production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler() in /var/www/html/ebutor-laravel/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php:59

PHP : 7.2
Composer Version : 1.10.2

While running composer install and update it throws this error.

Comment: You may find community members are more likely to help if you provide some context for your question. if possible, provide more information on your compose dependencies, php version, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ rm composer.lock
$ rm -rf vendor
$ composer install
```